# Is it possible to distinguish operators += and + in class function __add__?

Tags: python, class, addition

I have a class, which contains some data. Operator + for two objects of such class should merge data from both objects and returns a new object. However, it should be much better if in the case of += operator would append data from the added object and return self. Here some pseudo code to demonstrate what I want to achieve.

```
class BiGData:
  def __init__(self):
    self.data=[]
  def __add__(self,x):
    if (this is just a +):
      newData=BigData()
      newData.data += self.data
      newData.data += x.data
      return newData
    else: #(this is the += case)
      self.data += x.data
      return self
```

If these two case of usage `__add__` function can be distinguished, Python code would much better read and understand! Consider this:

```
x,y=BigData(),BigData()
z = x + y # z is a new object of the BigData class, 
          # which collects all data from both x and y
          # but data in x and y are intacked
x += y    # just append data from y to x
          # data in x has been changed
```

Comment: As a general rule, `+=` is a different operator, so can be overriden separately. If it is not defined separately, the default implementation will just use `+` and reassign the result.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes I do understand now. Somehow __iadd__ sneaked behind my attention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

But if you implement [`__iadd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__) then `+=` will use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

`object.__iadd__(self, other)` for `+=`

`object.__radd__(self, other)` for `+`

see [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) for reference

Comment: `__iadd__` and just plain `__add__`. You only really want `__radd__` for weird cases and where addition is not commutative for some reason.